# Magento Update all products manufacturer using SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, attributes

I would like to update all of the products' manufacturer using SQL/mysql query shell.
How can I do this?

Comment: Do you know the SQL syntax for `UPDATE`?

Comment: Yes , I need the tables and fields name which should be used .. 
Do you know them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manufacturer value is stored using the EAV pattern, writing raw SQL to change these is nightmarish, use the ORM instead (with a setup script in your module sql directory).

```
$installer = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup();
$installer->startSetup();

$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach($products as $product) {
    $product->setManufacturer(...);
    $product->save();
}
$installer->endSetup();`
```

Comment: The idea that I want to set the manufacturer using first word of the product's name for example : 
Samsung Galaxy 
Apple iPad
Sony LCD
etc. 

So I want to add Samsung , Apple and Sony as the manufacturer of the products

Comment: Thanks very much I did it as the following

$installer = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup();
$installer->startSetup();
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach($products as $product) {
 $pieces = explode(" ", $product->getName());
 if (strtolower($pieces[0]) == "digium")
 {
  $product->setManufacturer(6);
 }
 if (strtolower($pieces[0]) == "polycom")
 {
  $product->setManufacturer(8);
 }
 if (strtolower($pieces[0]) == "grandstream")
 {
  $product->setManufacturer(9);
 }
 
 $product->save();
 sleep(2);
 
    }

Answer (score 1):

Use magmi,it is a better option when data size is huge.

Magmi link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Magmi Wiki : http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: Thanks very much , I installed it , how can I update manufacturer attribute using magmi ?